# Remove Object from ArrayList based on User Input

Tags: java, object, arraylist, iterator

I have an object that looks like this:

```
Account account = new Account (0, fName, sName, adr, city, pos, uniqueID);
```

I then put that object, via user input, to an ArrayList:

```
List<Account> newAcc = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

Here's the problem. I need a slick way to remove that object based on user input. This is what I've tried:

```
System.out.print("1. Client with Accounts.\n2. Client with Savings Accounts.\n3. Remove all Accounts.\n");
int inputRmv = in.nextInt();

case 1:
    for (Iterator i = newAcc.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        if (i.equals(rmvID)) {
            newAcc.remove(i);
```

---

This doesn't work. The object isn't removed this way.

Basically: is there a way to use user input and then iterate through the list to see if any object contains a string equivalent to any part of the object?

I am in dire need, so any help to send me in the right direction is immensely appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: Referred to the wrong array in the first post, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare the `Iterator` object with the `rmvId`. This will always return `false`, because they are not of the same `type`. I guess you want to check if the iterator's next object's id is equal to `rmvId`.

So use `i.next()` to get the next `SavingsAccount`, compare it's id with the `rmvId` and then remove it through the `Iterator`.

```
  SavingsAccount sa = i.next();
  if (sa.getId().equals(rmvID)) { // just an example.. I don't know how you access the 
                                  // saving account's id nor it's type. This example expect
                                  // it is `Integer`
     i.remove();
  }
```

If the `SavingsAccount` id is of type `int` you can compare it this way `sa.getId() == rmvID`.

Comment: Also, make sure `Account` overrides `equals()` (and `hashCode()`).

Answer (score 0):

Check the objects attribute whether it contains given id , and then remove the relevant object in the list by its index

```
for(int i=0;i<newSacc.size();i++){
    if (newSacc.get(i).getId().equals(rmvID)){
        newSacc.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, you should loop from end of list to remove anything from list. Otherwise, with list [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], you'll get [1, 1] after removing 1 from list instead of an empty list.